# Json returns the object as undefined

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

The similar questions didnt work for me. I have a AJAX GET request. When I show the entire json in the console log it works, but I cant select a single object from it.

My JS

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8092/api/getdata",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (data) {

            console.log(data["date"]);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }
    });
```

This code returns `undefined` but if I only use `console.log(data)` it shows everything. Not sure what to do from here.

This is the output when I use `console.log(data)`

```
{
   "date": "04-06-2020",
   "id": 4
}
```

SS when I use `console.log(data)`

[image]

SS when I use `console.log(data["id"])`

[image]

Comment: What does it show when you just log `data` ?

Comment: sorry, I wasn't sure how to say it. I can show the everything in the json but i cant select a specific object value in it. eg : I cant choose `id` from `"id":1,"date":"20-01-2020"`

Comment: If you get a JSON, then it is a string and you first need to convert it to an object by `var obj = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: @DNT I got this error when I used that ` Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: That means the JSON is incorrect. It should start with `{` and end with `}` with correct JSON syntax in between.

Comment: @DNT yeah my bad, it had those as well

Comment: Do you get a correct JSON string in `data` or not? That JSON, if it is a string, then it is missing commas and  `id::4` should be `id:4`. This `{"date": "04-06-2020", "id": 4}` is correct. Without the comma, it is not.

Comment: @DNT I did. I updated my question with the output

Comment: You don't get `Unexpected token o` if there is no `o` in your json

Comment: ^ well you do, if you have an object and not a string, because then it will convert to `[object Object]` which has an `o` in position 1.

Comment: (which makes it stranger that `data["date"]` doesn't work.) Are you sure that the code you showed is the exact code you used, and not some "simplified" version of it without the bug?

Comment: @CherryDT nope, I copied the entire code, except its wrapped with `function getLeave(){ }` but thats just to call this function when a button is clicked

Comment: Usually we don't want screenshots because they are actually harder to work with than text, but in this case it could be helpful (because it has more context): Can you please put `console.log(data); console.log(data["date"]);` (both of them) into your code and then show a _screenshot_ of the console output?

Comment: What does this `console.log(Object.prototype.toString(data));`  show? If it is `[object Object]` then you can check a property by `if (data.hasOwnProperty('date')) ...` and if the property is not there, then you are not getting what you expected.

Comment: @CherryDT added them to my question

Comment: Ah that explains everything. Writing my answer.

Comment: >! data is an array with a single object. use data[0]["date"] instead

Comment: Does it work like this ? console.log(data.date);

Comment: You left out the `[ ]` when you posted the text from your console.log. If you check the screenshot you can see that your data is an array with one entry at entry `[0]` So you need to use `data[0].date` or `data[0]['date']`

Comment: thanks a lot everyone. I completely missed the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you didn't show us the complete output of `console.log(data)` in your question, there are square brackets (`[   ]`) missing around it! According to your console screenshot, you get an *array*, with one object in it.

So the structure is:

```
[
  {
    "date": "04-06-2020",
    "id": 4
  }
]
```

Therefore, you need to access the **first array element** (using `[0]`) to get the object itself, and from there the property `date`, like this:

```js
console.log(data[0].date)
```

(Of course, `data[0]["date"]` works too, but in my opinion the dot-based property access looks cleaner.)

Comment: Oh. the array part completely went over my head. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Keep in mind that this sort of structure would usually indicate that you may as well receive 0 entries, or 10, not necessarily 1. I don't know what API you use there but check that out, make sure to check `data.length` too - otherwise you will crash with `Cannot read property 'date' of undefined` when the length is zero (because `data[0]` will then be undefined), and you may miss something important when there is more than one item in the list because you look only at the first.

Answer (score 1):

`data["date"]` is used for object which has date attribute. But in your response is an array
you need to say `data[0]["date"]` or `data[0].date`